# Splitting or Distributing very large data on PostgresQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql

I have a dedicated server with `10x1TB`. I can do RAID and make them as single one. But this gave me 10TB data. What will happen if PostgreSQL data exceeds 10TB? Which will exceed soon (I have a special software that requires TBs of database and writes/reads always)

Is there any method/feature in `PostgreSQL` or `pgpool-II` to add more servers or hdds when needed. What should I do to prevent such scenario?

Also, I have `GlusterFS` infrastructure, Should I deploy my database in that? Or is there any `filesystem` exactly for this?

**Note**: I know there is replicate. But my situation is splitting very large database on multiple disks or servers or distribute on filesystems like GlusterFS. *Like where server is full I add more and it continues to write...*

Comment: You can use [tablespaces](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) to store each table on their own disk. A common way to shard data across multiple servers is to use foreign data wrapper. With inheritance this can even be setup to look like one big table

Comment: 1) Table-spaces for split tables
2) Disk arrays - for make single disk

In any case - You must understand Your data growing plans, and choose configurations based on this data

Comment: What about citusdata? I found that it can shard tables. But it also states that window functions are not supported and i have dozens of window functions. I think i will stick with tablespaces and assign nfs for it.

Comment: Look, start from calculate - what data You plan have after 2 years?

Comment: a lot of data. I can assume it will be PBs. This is what i want to do exactly. I want to start somewhere that i wont fail next year or so.

Comment: a lot of data - wrong answer. ( :-) , nothing personal). YOU MUST have a plan. What biggest single table? What type of queries You plan run over this data? It possible to use partitioning - proper use, when 99% queries over active partition, but not over all data, and etc. Because simple answer (from my past practice) - no problem, just bough Top-levrl EMC with SSD, and it cover all Your needs (but cost of this ...)

Comment: @a_vlad no i don't mind. you are telling the truth. I never thought like this way. Now, I will do a plan and seperate each table to the proper partitioning. When it comes to that level i will look for further solutions.

Comment: Just for not make 1000 post in comments - it must be much more information for proper answer. It very depend from - number of users, number of queries, type of queries and etc. Any of solution could work, but with different results for different loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @a_vlad stated, you should do have a plan. Also, for later use I would like to recommend you guys two things.

1. Tablespace
2. Citus Data (distribute data across workers)

> Citus is a distributed database that combines the low-latency requests that power real-time applications with high throughput, interactive analytics on billions of events.
>
> Citus does this by extending PostgreSQL to distribute your workload across multiple hosts, leveraging the memory, storage, and processing power of multiple machines.

[Read more](https://www.citusdata.com/product)